# Display Password from the text Box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a TextBox Control with the `PasswordChar = '*';` 
Now I want to show the password if user checks a checkbox.
Strangely it is not working and I am not able to see my passsword

Here is my code

```
if (DisplayPasswordCheckBox.Checked)
     PasswordTB.PasswordChar = char.Parse("\0");
else
     PasswordTB.PasswordChar = char.Parse("*");
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here ?

**Edited :** If you are using `UseSystemPasswordChar = true`, turn that off before changing the password char to get the result on screen

Comment: try replacing char.Parse("\0"); with string.Empty;

Comment: It says that Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'

Comment: of course, PaswwordChar would of type char not string. my mistake.... @Christos answer should work fine

Comment: Did you add an event listener to your checkbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change you code to the following one:

```
if (DisplayPasswordCheckBox.Checked)
    PasswordTB.PasswordChar = '\0';
else
    PasswordTB.PasswordChar = '*';
```

You don't have to parse anything. So you don't need to use `char.Parse()` method.

For more information about the property called `PasswordChar`, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It says that Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'

Comment: please try the updated one and let me know. I am sorry being wrong before. Thanks !

Comment: My Mistake, Even My Code was working, but I had set PasswordTB.UseSystemPasswordChar = true; , that's why this code wasn't working. Your link to MSDN Page say that The UseSystemPasswordChar property has precedence over the PasswordChar property.

Comment: @user3745020 hm sometimes we can get in trouble from this type of errors. Anyways that counts is there wouldn't be next time that you will face a similar problem. That's +1 to your experience. However, I am glad that at least I helped this way.

Answer (score 2):

From msdn:

> The character used to mask characters entered in a single-line TextBox
>   control. Set the value of this property to 0 (character value) if you
>   do not want the control to mask characters as they are typed. Equals 0
>   (character value) by default.

Source: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx)

So the solution is

```
if (DisplayPasswordCheckBox.Checked)
     PasswordTB.PasswordChar = '\0'; //msdn says: 0 as character value.
else
     PasswordTB.PasswordChar = '*';
```

Other solution:

```
PasswordTB.PasswordChar = (char)0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hopefully it will help

```
    if (DisplayPasswordCheckBox.Checked)
        PasswordTB.PasswordChar = '\0';
    else
        PasswordTB.PasswordChar = char.Parse("*");
```